# How to delete right elements from a linked list?

Tags: c++, list, memory-management, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing this code to learn by my self how to work correctly with files and strings. I've managed successfully with the part of reading and writing to the file but stacked for a while at the point of deleting all the elements from the list.

The problem is that after deleting all elements from the list I'm trying to use function printAll, it doesn't stop as it should happen and I don't understand where is the problem. May be some of you can open my eyes on the bug and help fix it.

So, this code is implementation of single linked list class named `Unit`, where variables are strings and vectors of strings:

```
class Unit {
 public:
Unit();//constructor
void printAllUnits(Unit *head);//-v
void printUnit(Unit *unit);//-v
Unit *insert(Unit *head,Unit *element);//-v
Unit *getNextUnit(Unit **unit);//-v

Unit *MergeBySN(Unit *leftPtr ,Unit *rightPtr);//-v
void SplitListBySn(Unit* head,Unit** left, Unit** right);//-v
int menuSelection(int correct);//prints a menu-v
void findAndPrintUnitByType(Unit *head, string searchString);
void findAndPrintUnitBySN(Unit *head, string number);
void findAndPrintUnitBySNType(Unit *head,string type, string number);
void findAndPrintUnitByCell(Unit *head, string cell);
void findAndPrintUnitByUnitLocation(Unit *head, string location);
void findAndPrintUnitByDate(Unit *head, string date);
Unit *readFromFile(Unit *head);
void writeToNewFile(Unit *head);
void addToFile(Unit *head);
int checkNumber(string *numberStr);

Unit *deleteUnit(Unit *unit, string type, string sn);//-v
void deleteAll(Unit *unit);

int getChoice(int lower,int upper);
void SortListBySn(Unit **unit);//-v
Unit *SortListByType(Unit *unit);//-v
void mainmenu();//-v
Unit *subInsert(Unit *head,Unit *element);
~Unit(); //destructor

**/*variables*/**
string Type;//type of unit 
string SN;//serial number of the unit
int occur;//number of occurences of this serial number during service
vector<string> Cell;//phisical location 
vector<string> Date;//vactor to hold the dates of changes
vector<string> unitLocation;
Unit *next;//link to next unit
};
```

here are some implementations of the functions deleteAll and printAll and constructor with destructor:

```
 /*constructor*/
 Unit::Unit(){
    Type.clear();
    SN.clear();
    occur=1;
    Cell.clear();
    unitLocation.clear();
    next=NULL;
    Date.clear();
 }
 /*function to print all elements in the list*/
 void Unit::printAllUnits(Unit *head){
  Unit *tmp;
  tmp = head;
  cout<<endl;
  if (tmp == NULL)
  {
    cout<<endl<<"There is no units, Nothing to Print.\n"<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"      Type       SN      Cell    UnitLocations    Date   "<<endl;
    cout<<"     ------    ------   ------  --------------   ------  "<<endl;
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        printUnit(tmp);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;cout<<endl;
   }
  }
  /*function to print specific unit*/
 void Unit::printUnit(Unit *unit){
   int i=1;
   string type;
   string cell;
   string sn;
   string location;
   string date;
   if(unit!=NULL){
   type=unit->Type;
   sn=unit->SN;
   cell=unit->Cell[0];
   location=unit->unitLocation[0];
   date=unit->Date[0];
   cout<<"\t"<<type<<"\t"<<sn<<"\t"<<cell<<"\t\t"<<location<<"\t"<<date<<endl;
   for(;i < unit->Cell.size();i++){
            cell=unit->Cell[i];
            location=unit->unitLocation[i];
            date=unit->Date[i];
            cout<<"\t\t\t"<<cell<<"\t\t"<<location<<"\t"<<date<<endl;
    }
       cout<<"Occurency:\t"<<unit->occur<<endl;
   }
 }
 /*destructor*/
 Unit::~Unit(){
    this->Cell.~vector();
    this->Date.~vector();
    this->unitLocation.~vector();
    this->Type.~basic_string();
    this->SN.~basic_string();

    }
/*function to insert element in to list by making a decision after what SN to insert it(kind of     insertion sort)*/

 Unit *Unit::insert(Unit *head,Unit *element){
     Unit *currElement;
     //*if empty list
    if(head==NULL){
            return element;
    }//if
//*if empty
    if(element->SN < head->SN){
            element->next=head;
            return element;
    }//if

    currElement=head;
    //*compare the serial numbers of elements

    //*if more
 for(;currElement->next != NULL;currElement=currElement->next){
            if(element->SN < currElement->next->SN)
        break;
}

//*equal numbers
if(currElement->SN==element->SN){//if SN is equal
    if(currElement->Type.compare(element->Type)==0){//if types are the same
        currElement->Date.push_back(element->Date[0]);
        currElement->occur++;
        currElement->Cell.push_back(element->Cell[0]);
        currElement->unitLocation.push_back(element->unitLocation[0]);
    }
return head;
}


//*put new element between current element and it's next elment
//(if currelement is last then curentelemnt's next ==NULL)
element->next=currElement->next;
currElement->next=element;
return head;
  }
  /*main prog*/
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
bool flag=0;
string str;
string *type;//type of unit (
string *sern;//serial number of the unit
string *cell;//phisical location
string *date;//vactor to hold the dates 
string *unitlocation;
Unit *head1=NULL;


Unit *tmp=new Unit;
    /*getting data*/
cin>>tmp->Type;
cin>>tmp->SN;
cin>>str;tmp->Cell.push_back(str);
cin>>str;tmp->Date.push_back(str);
cin>>str;tmp->unitLocation.push_back(str);
/*inserting in to the list*/
    head1=head1->insert(head1,tmp);
head1->printAllUnits(head1);
head1->deleteAll(head1);
head1->printAllUnits(head1);
return 0;
 }
```

The problem occurs after making a deleteAll action, as I saw in debugger (VS2008) fields Type and SN have `<badptr>` and when trying to print list (although it's empty) the program makes an attempt to do it and crashes although I've made a check for NULL or empty list.

So the question what is wrong with the function **`deleteALL`**? How should I implement it?

Comment: I see you are explicitly invoking destructors. This alone is totally wrong, because the destructors will also get invoked automatically.

Comment: Where's the function deleteAll?

Comment: Please show us your implementation of "deleteAll". It is not in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The error is simple - you are trying to print `head1` after deleting it. That won't work — you should not call methods on deleted objects.

Just after a quick look, there is a number of problems with your code:

- You don't need any of those `clear` calls in the constructor. Vectors are empty on initialization in any case.
- You should not call destructors explicitely. They will get called automatically.
- You don't need to make a temporary copy of `head` in `printAllUnits`.
- There are two errors in the sentence: "There is no units, Nothing to Print."

There is a number of ways to implement `deleteAll`. Here is a simple one:

```
Unit * Unit::deleteAll(Unit * head)
{
    vector<Unit*> units;
    while (head)
    {
        units.push_back(head);
        head = head->next;
    }
    for (int i(0); i != units.size(); ++i)
        delete units.at(i);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    head1 = head1->deleteAll(head1);
    Unit::printAllUnits(head1);
}
```